# Unknown Icon in LabVIEW

Tags: logic, structure, labview

I came across a manual for a product I am using with LabVIEW, and it has some symbols and structures I have not seen before. These have been highlighted in the attached image as 1. and 2.

[image: Labview Diagram showing a multiplexer setup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are common functions included in core LabVIEW.  If you have LabVIEW installed check "Help > Show Context Help" which will enable a little window with information about the stuff under your cursor.

1. [Logical Shift](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/logical_shift/)
2. [Split Number](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/split_number/)